# Get first and last Fields in a Java Object

Tags: java, object, field

I have an Object that I'm supposed to get the first and last fields for. Normally, I'd use the getters for the fields in question, but since I don't know what those fields are...

I tried the get() method, but apparently that only works on ArrayLists. Anyone know of anything out there that's object/class compatible?

Comment: presumably you'd need to use [the reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) to figure out what the first and last fields are, and get them that way. However, there's almost never a good reason to use the reflection API. What's the problem you're actually trying to solve by getting the first and last fields? There's probably an easier way to solve it

Comment: And what do "first" and "last" mean?

Comment: do you know the dynamic type of the java object? can you cast the object to this type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve fields’ names and types using Java reflection. Call [`Class#getDeclaredFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()).

```
Field[] allFields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

Get the first and last elements of that array. Call `get…` methods on the [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) class.